# Ant build - javac task - exclude a dir then include a subdir

Tags: java, ant, javac, build.xml

I have a tree like this

```
path/a
path/b
path/c
path/d/da
path/d/db
path/d/dc
```

Now in my javac task i want to

- Compile everything in `path/`
- Exclude everything in `path/d/`
- Compile everything in `path/d/db/`

Like this:

```
path/a
path/b
path/c
path/d/db
```

I played with include/exclude and patternset but i couldn't achieve what i need.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The [`<difference>` and `<union>` set operations](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#setlogic) will be handy for what you need.

The following Ant script shows how to combine several `<fileset>` elements into one:

```
<project name="ant-javac-include-and-exclude" default="run" basedir=".">
    <target name="run">
        <fileset id="all-files" dir="path">
            <include name="**"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset id="files-under-d" dir="path">
            <include name="d/**"/>
        </fileset>
        <fileset id="files-under-d-db" dir="path">
            <include name="d/db/**"/>
        </fileset>

        <!-- Matches all files under a, b, c -->
        <difference id="all-files-NOT-under-d">
            <fileset refid="all-files"/>
            <fileset refid="files-under-d"/>
        </difference>

        <!-- Combine all files under a, b, c and under d/db -->
        <union id="files-to-compile">
            <difference refid="all-files-NOT-under-d"/>
            <fileset refid="files-under-d-db"/>
        </union>

        <!-- Convert the absolute paths in "files-to-compile" to relative-->
        <!-- paths. Also, "includes" of <javac> requires a comma-separated -->
        <!-- list of files. -->
        <pathconvert property="union-path" pathsep=",">
            <union refid="files-to-compile"/>
            <map from="${basedir}/" to=""/>
        </pathconvert>

        <javac
            srcdir="."
            includes="${union-path}"
            includeantruntime="false"
        />
    </target>
</project>
```

The above steps can be combined into the following:

```
<pathconvert property="union-path" pathsep=",">
    <union>
        <difference>
            <fileset dir="path">
                <include name="**"/>
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="path">
                <include name="d/**"/>
            </fileset>
        </difference>
        <fileset dir="path">
            <include name="d/db/**"/>
        </fileset>
    </union>
    <map from="${basedir}/" to=""/>
</pathconvert>

<javac
    srcdir="."
    includes="${union-path}"
    includeantruntime="false"
/>
```